# How do I prevent my sugar coating from melting on my gummy bears

Tags: candy

I am making homemade gummy bears and I cannot prevent the sugar coating from melting way into a puddle of watered sugar? I tried drying the gummy bears for a day but it still melts away.

Comment: Under what conditions are you drying them for a day? An answer under https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11131/problem-with-gummy-bears-being-too-much-like-jelly?rq=1 mentions a "drying room" in a commercial setup, where they also stay for a day, but I suspect they will have controlled humidity levels there.

Comment: Are you coating with caster sugar, granulated, or confectioner's?

Comment: I've recently bought commercial jellies whose sugar coating started melting together on a hot day. Could be storage related as well / instead of prep

Answer (score 1):

I usually dry mine for approximately 48 hours. I’ve used cornstarch, regular sugar etc and found I like regular sugar with a bit of citric acid I pulse to powder in my blender. Once you’ve got the taste you want put the powdered sugar/citric acid in a large baggie and dump in your gummies (you will most likely have to repeat a few times dependent on the # of gummies made. I let them sit for an hour or so to set the outside. I keep 10 with me in a dispensary bottle and refill as needed.

Plain cornstarch can work as well.
FYI I used 3ounces of jello, 1/2 cup of water, 1 and 1/2 packets of Knox gelatin. Once gelatin blooms it’s very granular

- cooking on low heat (Stir frequently so gelatin doesn’t clump but stir with a slow hand getting base off the sides and along the bottom.., if it starts to boil remove from heat. Once gelatin and Jello start getting touchpad remove from heat add your concentrate and an emulsifier (I like glycerin the best for the finished texture but soy or sunflower letchicin is also a good emulsifier.
- Stir until you see no separation of oils. Watch out for foam and bubbles. Scrape what you can off but honestly I didn’t do anything the first time it happened and the gummies were less clear..
  Happy Candy Making

Answer (score 0):

It is probably worth providing a recipe for what you're doing, but what about rolling them in a mix if iceing sugar and cornflour

Answer (score 0):

you just have to decrease the moisture content in your gummy bears recipe. the gummy bears must not be much sticky when they come out of the mould.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need more gelatin in your recipe (or less water). You can also try a hair dryer to dry them completely.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may need higher brix.  Deposit >74 (absolute minimum) brix
2. Not curing long enough before coating- give them time to breathe then sand for better results.  If you wait longer than 24H you may need a little mist of water to coat
3. Not enough sanding- more of it needed because various reasons